# cluster bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I am trying to create a clustered bar plot for 3 different types of precipitation data. I've been doing various searches, how this might be done in R with a similar data set. However, I couldn't find any good help.
[image]

This is the dataset I am currently using. I have tried adding multiple `geom_bar()` but that didn't work out. See attempt below:

```
ggplot(ppSAcc,aes(x=date,y=as.numeric(Precipitation)))+geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(color="blue"),show.legend=FALSE,size=1)+
    geom_bar(ppMAcc,stat="identity",aes(x=date,y=as.numeric(Precipitation),color="purple"),show.legend = FALSE,size=1)+
    labs(title="Accumulated Solid Precipitation (Snow)",y="Precipitation (mm)")
```

In my second attempt, I tried creating a dataframe which includes all three precipitation types.

```
data<-data.frame(date=ppSAcc$date,snow=ppSAcc$Precipitation,mixed=ppMAcc$Precipitation,rain=ppRAcc$Precipitation)
```

Which gave me the dataframe shown above.
This is where I am stuck. I started coding ggplot `ggplot(data,aes(x=date)))+geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity")` but I'm not sure how to write the code such that I will have three columns(snow, mixed, rain) for each year. I'm not sure how to set the `aes()` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape your dataframe into a longer format before to plot it in `ggplot2`. You can use `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df %>% pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ymd(date), y= val, fill = var))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset by following this guide: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I couldn't get the ```pivot_longer()``` to work. I believe my syntax is way off. Right now I have this:
```df %>% pivot_longer(date=ppSAcc$date, snow = ppSAcc$Precipitation,mixed = ppMAcc$Precipitation,rain = ppRAcc$Precipitation, values_to = precipitation) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ymd(date), y= precipitation, fill = var))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())```

Comment: but I just thought of another way, and I think I got it to work.
```df<-tibble(date=ppSAcc$date,snow=runif(10,0,0.12166677),mixed=runif(10,0,13.68336633),rain=runif(10,0,0.1233333))
df<-df %>% gather(keys,Precipitation,snow:rain)  
ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=Precipitation))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",aes(fill=keys))```

Comment: Just replace `df` by the name of your dataframe, the remaining should work as I wrote it.

Comment: Do you only have 4 columns on your dataframe ?

Comment: Yes only 4 columns. Date, snow, mixed, and rain

Comment: Ok, so replace `df` by the name of your dataframe and you should get your plot. Do you have all librairies installed and loaded ?

Comment: I changed the name of my dataframe and now it says ```pivot_longer()``` cannot be found. But I have loaded all the suggested libraries

Comment: What is your version of tidyr ? `pivot_longer` has been introduce in 1.0.0 version of tidyr and is dedicated to replace `gather`

Comment: Version 0.8.3. Which is probably why it isn't working.

Comment: Yes, please upgrade `tidyr` and you will see my code will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211915/discussion-between-bubs-and-dc37).